# C++ sorting a vector of shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector, shared-ptr

I'm trying to sort a vector of shared_ptrs to Food objects.
Food class is defined as:

```
class Food {
private:
// Human-readable description of the food, e.g. "all-purpose wheat
// flour". Must be non-empty.
std::string _description;

// Human-readable description of the amount of the food in one
// sample, e.g. "1 cup". Must be non-empty.
std::string _amount;

// Number of grams in one sample; must be non-negative.
int _amount_g;

// Energy, in units of kilocalories (commonly called "calories"), in
// one sample; must be non-negative.
int _kcal;

// Number of grams of protein in one sample; most be non-negative.
int _protein_g;

public:
Food(const std::string& description,
    const std::string& amount,
    int amount_g,
    int kcal,
    int protein_g)
    : _description(description),
    _amount(amount),
    _amount_g(amount_g),
    _kcal(kcal),
    _protein_g(protein_g) {

    assert(!description.empty());
    assert(!amount.empty());
    assert(amount_g >= 0);
    assert(kcal >= 0);
    assert(protein_g >= 0);

}
const std::string& description() const { return _description; }
const std::string& amount() const { return _amount; }
int amount_g() const { return _amount_g; }
int kcal() const { return _kcal; }
int protein_g() const { return _protein_g; }

};
```

using

```
// Alias for a vector of shared pointers to Food objects.
using FoodVector = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Food>>;
```

My sorting algorithm is:

```
std::unique_ptr<FoodVector> greedy_max_protein(const FoodVector& foods,
int total_kcal) 
{
std::unique_ptr<FoodVector> result(new FoodVector); 
int result_cal = 0;                             
sort(foods.begin(), foods.end(), sortByProtein); //sorting error
...
```

The error is occuring with the sort function here ^^ and my sortByProtein function is:

```
bool sortByProtein(const std::shared_ptr<Food>&lhs, const std::shared_ptr<Food>&rhs)
{
return lhs->protein_g() > rhs->protein_g();

}
```

I keep getting the binary'='no operator found which takes a left hand operand type 'const std::shared_ptr' or there is no acceptable conversion. I've tried creating my own sort function but i get the same error. Do i need to overload operator= in my class ? If so how do i go about doing that? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

fixed the issue by creating a new pointer:

```
FoodVector *sorted = new FoodVector(foods);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `const FoodVector& foods,` - You cannot sort (or otherwise modify) `foods` if it is `const`.

Comment: so, if i create a new vector from the foods vector that is not const then i can sort it with the sort algorithm?

Comment: @DallasM, yes, or just remove `const` modificator

Comment: okay i got it to work thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't use `new` unless you know you really nees to - which is not true here.

Answer (score 1):

I chopped down and isolated the problem.
Before removing the "const" I got the same error you were getting.
But this compiles.

```
#include <iostream>

//:For: std::vector
#include <vector>

//:For: std::shared_ptr
#include <memory> 

//:For: std::sort 
#include<algorithm>

class Food{ /* SomeLogicHere */ };
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Food>> FoodVector;

bool operator==(
    std::shared_ptr<Food> lhs,
    std::shared_ptr<Food> rhs
){
    return true; //TODO: Actual Comparison Logic
}

bool sortByProtein(
    std::shared_ptr<Food> lhs,
    std::shared_ptr<Food> rhs
)  {
    //:Dont Care about implementation.
    //:Just want minimal example that
    //:gets the error.
    return false;

}

std::unique_ptr<FoodVector> greedy_max_protein(
    FoodVector foods,
    int total_kcal 
){

    sort(foods.begin(),foods.end(),sortByProtein);

}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the function that is trying to sort

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<FoodVector> greedy_max_protein(const FoodVector& foods,
>   int total_kcal) 
> {
>     std::unique_ptr<FoodVector> result(new FoodVector); 
>     int result_cal = 0;                             
>     sort(foods.begin(), foods.end(), sortByProtein); //sorting error
> ```

`std::sort()` relies on the first two arguments being non-`const` iterators - i.e. that can be used to change the values they refer to.   It is, after all, rather tough to sort a container if the elements cannot be reassigned.

`foods` is a `const` reference to a `FoodVector`  (aka `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Food> >`)  so the `begin()` and `end()` functions are `const`, and return a type `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Food> >::const_iterator`.    That does not meet requirements of `std::sort()`.

To fix the problem, either

1. remove the `const` qualifier from the first argument of the function `greedy_max_protein()`.  Be aware this means that the function may change the elements of the passed `FoodVector`, and the caller will not be able to pass a `const FoodVector`;
2. Create a copy locally in the function and sort that.   This is appropriate if the working of the function needs a sorted vector, but the caller requires that the passed vector remains unchanged.

Comment: Ya i just did what you described in option 2. Thanks!